# Convert armatures to empties while retaining animation data

Tags: animation, armature, conversion

I have a fully animated model that uses armatures. However, in order for it to be exported (using a DTS exporter in specific for Blender 2.78), I need to use armatures instead of empties.

Is there a way to turn the armatures into empties without having to reanimate everything? I've tried exporting this as a .bvh file and importing it as a .bvh with the target as "Object," but that just puts it far away and it just isn't in the right position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got you correctly you may transfer the animation data from bones to empties and then bake it to keyframes.

Add an *Empty* in the same location as keyframed bone and give it a ***Copy Transforms*** constraint. Set the Head/Tail value to 0.500 to place it in the middle of a bone.
[image]

Select an *Empty*, go to the *Animation* bookmark of a *Tool Shelf* (<kbd>T</kbd>) and press the ***Bake Action*** button. Check all the checkboxes there and set the ***Object*** as a bake data type. Delete the bone finally.
[image]